# What are all validation rules for input type "Password"

Tags: validation, passwords, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I want to display a message on my HTML page to instruct users for what is allowed in Password field. 
I have following in my HTML markup

```
<input type="Password" data-val="true" name="password"/>
```

What are all allowed values for HTML Password inputs?

Comment: dont know why its downvoted.. but I am sure I have done enough research before posting this.. this isn't as straight-forward to find in google to award a downvote!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using the `data-val` attribute, i assume you're using the unobtrusive version of [jquery-validate](/questions/tagged/jquery-validate).

See [this article](http://denverdeveloper.wordpress.com/2012/09/26/some-things-ive-learned-about-jquery-unobtrusive-validation/) for a comprehensive list of validation rules.

Answer (score 2):

```
<input type="Password" data-val="true" name="password" required maxlength=”15” minlength=”4” pattern=”[1-4]{5}” />
```

**HTML**

```
<form name="ValidationForm">
    Password: <input type="password" id="password1"/>
    Confirm Password:<input type="password" id="password2"/>
    <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
</form>
```

**JS**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function () {
    document.getElementById("password1").onchange = validatePassword;
    document.getElementById("password2").onchange = validatePassword;
}
function validatePassword(){
var pass2=document.getElementById("password2").value;
var pass1=document.getElementById("password1").value;
if(pass1!=pass2)
    document.getElementById("password2").setCustomValidity("Passwords Don't Match");
else
    document.getElementById("password2").setCustomValidity('');  
//empty string means no validation error
}
</script>
```

sure you can use JQuery rather than row JS

Comment: you can make the pattern as you like,

Answer (score 2):

http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/input.password.html

> Value: Any string that contains no line feed (U+000A, “LF”) or carriage return (U+000D, “CR”) characters.

In other words, by default you can put pretty much any text in there you like, with the two exceptions above.